# Angular directives disappear after POST

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've made a POST request to get html of block. Here is my post:

```
 $scope.changeMenu = function () {
        $http({method: "POST", url: "/menu"}).then(function (response) {
                    $scope.selected_menu_item = response.data;
                },
                function () {
                    $scope.selected_menu_item = response.data;
                });
    }
```

Block, where I display received html::

```
<div ng-bind-html="selected_menu_item" class="chosen-item">
```

Than I've get response:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs8s1.png)

But angular directives have been disappear in html document:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvjy6.png)

What is I have to do to get angular directives after POST?

Thanks

Comment: You can't use angular directives/bindings inside HTML that is inserted through `ng-bind-html`.

Answer (score 2):

The `ng-bind-html` directive doesn't $compile the data you pass it so the directives within that text won't be linked to a scope or processed for directives.  `ng-include` will compile the contents of the template you pass it but since you are working with the response from an $http request that is being sent with METHOD:'POST' just using ng-include won't work in that case.  If that were just a get request then ng-include can be used without the need for the extra script since ng-include will do the http request.  If that doesn't work let me know will post the code to do the $compile step yourself.

Comment: Thanks, it helped :)